# Angular component: How to check contents only after API call.subscribe has populated variable completely?

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a component that calls on an endpoint to populate a variable of type List which is a List of PaperNames.

papers: paperNameDTO;

I populate papers on the page loading in ngOnInit:

```
     ngOnInit() {
            this.fileService.getPaperNames().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('Entering here API call');
      this.papers = data['papers'];
    });

    if(this.papers.papersList.length > 0) {
       console.log('Entering filteredPapers');
       const filteredPapers = this.papers.papersList.filter(paper => paper.name 
       !== 'FINAL_YEAR' && paper.name !== 'FIRST_YEAR' );
       console.log('Final length is = ' + filteredPapers.length);
      }
   }
```

The goal is to exclude returned Strings with names 'FINAL_YEAR' and 'FIRST_YEAR' which i filter into another array of Strings.

Problem i face is this method does not work, when i check the console logs, the 
loop `if(this.tables.tables.length > 0)` gets entered first before `this.enquireService.getTableNames().subscribe(data =>`. Why is that so? And how could i accomplish this otherwise?

Comment: wrap your code inside subscribe.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesnt work. Somehow the data object becomes undefined and I cannot .filter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any functionality that directly depends on an asynchronous data should be inside the subscription. Please see here for more details on how to access asynchronous data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.fileService.getPaperNames().subscribe(data => {
    console.log('Entering here API call');
    this.papers = data['papers'];
    const filteredPapers = this.papers.papersList.filter(
      paper => paper.name !== 'FINAL_YEAR' && paper.name !== 'FIRST_YEAR');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a subscribe is used it means, sometime in the future something will happen. The code moves on to next statement where it immediately executes. If the next statement relies on a state inside the subscription it will not work. To fix, from the subscription call the function which need the data.